# ef4 group by and sum with condition on navigation

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have 2 tables

```
**table 1**
int tid
money money
datetime date
int serviceid
int type


**table2**
int id
int tid
status nvarchr()
```

I'm using Ef4. I have navigation property to both entities

i'm trying to get sum of money group by date [i also made a new class with this properties]

```
Total money
Total money of type [1]
total money where table2 status is a or b
```

how can I achieve that king of query 
THIS IS WHAT I GOT SO FAR :

```
return db.TBL1.Include("TBL2").Where(x => x.date >= startDate && x.date <= endDate && x.ServiceID == sid).GroupBy(e => new { e.Date.Value.Year, e.Date.Value.Month, e.Date.Value.Day }).AsEnumerable().Select(group => new entity c (Convert.ToInt32(group.Sum(x => x.Money)), Convert.ToInt32(group.Where(d => d.BillingType == 1).Sum(x => x.Money)),********what can i do here*****, Convert.ToDateTime(group.FirstOrDefault().Date))).AsEnumerable<billingReport>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return db.TBL1
         .Where(x => x.date >= startDate && 
                     x.date <= endDate && 
                     x.ServiceID == sid)
         .GroupBy(e => new 
         { 
             e.Date.Value.Year, 
             e.Date.Value.Month, 
             e.Date.Value.Day 
         })
         .Select(group => new billingReport
         {
             TotalMoney = Convert.ToInt32(group.Sum(x => x.Money), 
             TotalMoneyOfType1 = Convert.ToInt32(group.Where(d => d.BillingType == 1)
                                                      .Sum(x => x.Money)),
             TotalMoneyForStatus = group.Where(x=>x.TBL2.Any(y => y.Status == "a" || 
                                                                  y.Status == "b"))
                                        .Sum(x => x.Money), 
             Date = Convert.ToDateTime(group.FirstOrDefault().Date))
         })
         .ToList();
```